# How to generate procedural textures for pebbles/round stones?

Tags: texturing, procedural

How to generate textures like the pebbles shown below procedurally in Blender?

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you mean the textures of the individual rocks and not *a* texture *of* rocks, yeah?

Comment: Yes....textures of individual rocks please.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I found this jpeg file on my old computer that I had not used for a long time. This is a render of a POVRay scene file authored  by Jonathan Hunt (2008). Have any of our Blender experts experimented with POVRay in the past?